rook-ceph (rgw) s3 website doesn't redirect to the index.html
The config override:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: rook-config-override
  namespace: rook-ceph
data:
  config: |
    [global]
    osd_pool_default_size = 1
    rgw_enable_static_website = true
    rgw_enable_apis = s3, s3website
    
    [client.rgw]
    rgw_enable_static_website = true
    rgw_enable_apis = s3, s3website

The object store:
apiVersion: ceph.rook.io/v1
kind: CephObjectStore
metadata:
  name: example
  namespace: rook-ceph
spec:
  metadataPool:
    failureDomain: host
    replicated:
      size: 1
  dataPool:
    failureDomain: host
    replicated:
      size: 1
  #   erasureCoded:
  #     dataChunks: 4
  #     codingChunks: 2
  # preservePoolsOnDelete: true
  gateway:
    # sslCertificateRef:
    port: 80
    # securePort: 443
    instances: 1
  hosting:
    # advertiseEndpoint:
    #   dnsName: s3.rook-ceph.svc
    #   port: 80
    #   useTls: false
    dnsNames:
      - s3.example.org

And configure the bucket to be public readable and website enabled.
aws --endpoint http://s3.example.org s3 website s3://mybucket/ --index-document index.html --error-document error.html

the url http://mybucket.example.org/index.html renders the html but the root uri (http://mybucket.example.org) shows object lists in the bucket instead of rendering index.html
I have checked the ingress and direct curl to the service is same.
Can anyone help?!
